# clang-format: trailing comment after #endif is formatted incorrectly

Tags: c, clang-format

I have the following code in my program:

```c
#ifdef __UCOSII__

#define SCANCODE_HKEY1  SCANCODE_F1 ///< Horizontal key 1
#define SCANCODE_HKEY2  SCANCODE_F2 ///< Horizontal key 2
#define SCANCODE_HKEY3  SCANCODE_F3 ///< Horizontal key 4

#define SCANCODE_VKEY1  SCANCODE_1 ///< Vertical key 1
#define SCANCODE_VKEY2  SCANCODE_2 ///< Vertical key 2
#define SCANCODE_VKEY3  SCANCODE_3 ///< Vertical key 3

#endif  // __UCOSII__
```

I'm using `clang-format` to format the code, and in my `.clang-format` configuration file, I added the following options:

```yaml
...
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Always
  OverEmptyLines: 1
...
```

The resulting formatted code looks like this:

```c
#ifdef __UCOSII__

#define SCANCODE_HKEY1  SCANCODE_F1  ///< Horizontal key 1
#define SCANCODE_HKEY2  SCANCODE_F2  ///< Horizontal key 2
#define SCANCODE_HKEY3  SCANCODE_F3  ///< Horizontal key 4

#define SCANCODE_VKEY1  SCANCODE_1   ///< Vertical key 1
#define SCANCODE_VKEY2  SCANCODE_2   ///< Vertical key 2
#define SCANCODE_VKEY3  SCANCODE_3   ///< Vertical key 3

#endif                               // __UCOSII__
```

As you can see, the comment between `#ifdef` and `#endif` is formatted correctly, but the comment after `#endif` is not formatted the way I want it to be. I want it to be indented two spaces after `#endif`, but it is not doing that. What can I do to achieve the desired result? Are there any options available to achieve this?

Comment: remove ```OverEmptyLines: 1```. This means that you want to allign comment even if they are separated by one empty line. Or maybe add an extra empty line before your ```#endif```

Comment: Thanks your methods, they are both feasible and have temporarily solved my problem. However, the results are not exactly what I expected. For example, adding two spaces before `#endif` looks very abrupt. Removing `OverEmptyLines: 1` would cause the macro definition to fail to align the two sections of comments due to the presence of an extra empty line. Is there currently any option or action in clang-format that can effectively solve this problem?

Comment: try to add this at your ```.clang-format``` file this ```AlignEscapedNewlines: DontAlign```

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on this issue. Okay, I will use the two solutions you provided earlier. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the `OverEmptyLines: 1`.

`clang-format` does not distinguish between "endif trailing comment" and "other trailing comment". It treats them the same. You either need to lower the `OverEmptyLines:` or put more lines before `#endif`.